# Animate background fill from left to right using keyframes animation one by one

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions, keyframe

I want to create animation like progressbar for that I have written following code

[My code](https://jsfiddle.net/vedankita/01qmfLzv/4/)

```css
.box {
  width: 26px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, black 50%);
  -webkit-animation: progressbar 1s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: progressbar 1s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: progressbar 1s ease infinite;
  animation: progressbar 1s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progressbar {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

My problem is all animation working at same time I want to add animation one bye one after one finishes in infinite loop like progress bar. Can **animation-timing-function: linear, steps(3, end);** will helps?  Please help me in this. Thanks

Comment: You can use `animation-delay` property for `2nd` & `3rd` div animation like `.box:nth-child(2){animation-delay: 2s}` & `.box:nth-child(3){animation-delay: 3s}` and fill background with `:before` OR `:after` css property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set `animation-delay` but for that, you'll need to remove the `!important`
also if there's an N amount of boxes you can add the style using JS or SCSS loop.

```css
.box {
  width: 26px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, black 50%);
  -webkit-animation: progressbar 1s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: progressbar 1s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: progressbar 1s ease infinite;
  animation: progressbar 1s ease infinite;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progressbar {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

if you wanted each one to stop before restarting you can do this:

```css
.box {
  width: 26px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, black 50%);
  -webkit-animation: progressbar 3s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: progressbar 3s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: progressbar 3s ease infinite;
  animation: progressbar 3s ease infinite;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  animation-name: progressbar1;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  animation-name: progressbar2;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progressbar {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  33%,
  100% {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes progressbar1 {
  0%,
  33% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  66%,
  100% {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes progressbar2 {
  0%,
  66% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not a result I want. I want infinite animation but one after another.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want the visual effect, here is an idea with one element and one animation

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 32% 0,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) 68% 0,
    linear-gradient(red, red),
    black;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:5px 100%,5px 100%,0% 100%;
  animation: progressbar 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes progressbar {
  100% {
    background-size:5px 100%,5px 100%,100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

If you want transparency we can add mask:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red, red) no-repeat,
    black;
  background-size:0% 100%;
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) right;
  -webkit-mask-size:30% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) right;
  mask-size:30% 100%;
  mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  animation: progressbar 1s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes progressbar {
  100% {
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
}
body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```